# Eclipse IDE, regular expression search and replace

Tags: c++, regex, eclipse, search, replace

I am attempting to setup my include statements in a large library. 
I need to edit specific include paths that start with "C:/Users/..." so the ending of the path is ".h"", and not ".h>"
Some paths that do not start with "C:/Users/..." need to keep the ".h>" hence why a simple find ".h>" & replace with ".h"" does not work.

What I have: `#include "C:/Users/{various paths to different headerfiles}.h>`

What I need: `#include "C:/Users/{various paths to different headerfiles}.h"`

There are hundreds of header files. In eclipse the regular expression option box in the menu (*search->file*) is the solution but I have not had success with using the correct expression. the closest I have gotten is:

Search:    `(\Q#include "C:/Users\E\w+\.h>)$`

Replace: `$1.h"`

Comment: Why do you have absolute include paths to begin with? Normally they're relative to the compiler's search paths. If anything, you should set them up like that, not keep using absolute paths.

Comment: Like [`(#include "C:/Users.*\.h")$`](https://regex101.com/r/v8q5aO/2)?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org), I would love to not use absolute paths but the sub folder header files are not finding themselves using their default include paths that all begin at the parent (/boost) folder. They find each other with absolute paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(#include "C:/Users.*\.h")$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v8q5aO/2)

**Details**

- `#include "C:/Users` - a literal string `#include "C:/Users`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `h"` - a literal `h"` substring
- `$` - end of string/line (depends on where you use it and if you pass `m` modifier or not).

The `(...)` create a capturing group, and you may refer to this group from the replacement pattern using the `$1` backreference.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I modified the expression to be fail safe for cases where extra spaces or a tab are inserted:  (#[ \t]*?include[ \t]*?".*\.h>)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Wiktor-Stribiżew !

For those who have a regular expression question Wiktor posted a very useful link to do your own testing, and try and solve the problem on your own.

(#include "C:/Users.*.h")$
Solves my searching problem.

I replaced my search with "$1fixThis" to give it a unique name so I could then do a basic search and replace to fix the quotes of my include paths.

Comment: You should have notified me via a comment so that I could post the solution since it worked for you.